# Detect if input placeholder is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder

I'm trying to find a way to detect if an input is currently showing a placeholder.

I know we can test whether or not placeholders are supported in a given browser, which I would use, but that's not what I'm asking here.

The [`:placeholder-shown`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder-shown/) pseudo class does exactly what I need, but the support for it is very low. Much lower than the support for placeholders in general. So I'm looking for an alternative method.

Note: The solution cannot rely on whether or not the input has changed or gained a value. Autofilled inputs neither have a technical value, nor have changed. Therefore the solution needs to truly detect the placeholder it'self.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, check to see if the `placeholder` attribute is being used by the element, and then check to see if the value of the input is empty:

```js
function placeholderActive(selector) {
  var el = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (el.getAttribute('placeholder') && el.value === '') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}


var a = placeholderActive('#test1'); // false
var b = placeholderActive('#test2'); // false
var c = placeholderActive('#test3'); // false
var d = placeholderActive('#test4'); // true

console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

```html
<input id="test1" name="test1" value="123">
<input id="test2" name="test2" placeholder="" value="123">
<input id="test3" name="test3" placeholder="Some Placeholder" value="123">
<input id="test4" name="test4" placeholder="Another placeholder" value="">
```

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, for most browsers we can use `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class to detect whether placeholder is shown or not.

```js
function placeholderActive(selector) {
  return !!document.querySelector(selector + ':placeholder-shown');
}
const a = placeholderActive('#test1'); // false
const b = placeholderActive('#test2'); // false
const c = placeholderActive('#test3'); // false
const d = placeholderActive('#test4'); // true

console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

```html
<input id="test1" name="test1" value="123">
<input id="test2" name="test2" placeholder="" value="123">
<input id="test3" name="test3" placeholder="Some Placeholder" value="123">
<input id="test4" name="test4" placeholder="Another placeholder" value="">
```

CSS-Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder-shown/

CanIUse: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown

Answer (score 0):

Add the `required` attribute to the input and then use `:invalid` to select the input that shows the placeholder.

This does not work with input types like email or inputs with a pattern attribute.

Using js is still the best option if you want it to work properly in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the required method only covers specific use cases, which many forms don't fall within. I'm looking for something less constrained.

Answer (score 0):

```
const hasPlaceholder = !!input.getAttribute("placeholder") // boolean
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.